# Connect ESP8622 to 74LV165

Tags: esp8266

I need to read bytes from parallel-to-serial register (74LV165A) at highest possible for ESP8266 speed.

My idea is to use the SPI interface, that provides CLK up to 80 MHz. But it looks like the NON-OS SDK provides only hspi-oriented routines using structures `SpiData` with cmd data fields, etc.

I am newbie in ESP8266 and would like to know if there is a way to implement my idea.

1. Set SPI frequency to 80MHz
2. Pull down SS for some period
3. Read received byte from some register

If this is not possible or too complex, I suggest to use 2 GPIOs (CLK and DATA) and form my byte in program cycle - what GPIOs (numbers) is better for high performance?

Comment: if new to ESPs, i would stick with pins 4+5 for now. in theory they are all the same (sans 16) performance-wise, but many of the pin's special functions and boot states can interfere with naively-attached hardware.

Comment: ok, @dandavis , yes, I remember that UART's is also mapped on GPIOs and I understand that by default there will be predefined state. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works!

Several steps should be implemented.

1. Connection of 74LV165 -> HSPI:

   `PL <- MOSI
   Q -> MISO
   CL <- HSPICLk`
2. MISO is using for creating PL high level with output of 0xff
3. In order to use HSPI properly the NodeMCU driver fits Ok: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/driver/spi.c.

For full-duplex communication use:

```
spi_mast_transaction(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0,-8)
```

The latter argument is negative for full-duplex communication.

It's good idea to use

```
SET_PERI_REG_MASK(SPI_USER(1), SPI_USR_MOSI|SPI_USR_MOSI_HIGHPART);
WRITE_PERI_REG(SPI_W8(1), 0xff);
```

for MOSI data value. In such way MOSI value can be set once at initialization while MISO data will be filled into SPI_W0..SPI_W7 without overlapping MOSI.

4. As far as 74LV165 gives output on falling edge of CLK, HSPI should be initialized with CPOL=1.